# Exchange 2013 on-prem: can't find origin of autoresponder message

Tags: exchange-2013, mailbox, auto-reply

I have a somewhat unexplainable behaviour with one of our mailboxes:

When the autoresponder is enabled, the sender of an email would get the normal autorespond (which is correctly displayed with the door Icon in Outlook) and another seperate message with an autoreply from former days which is displayed as a normal message in Outlook.

What i have checked so far:

- the users autoresponder configuration in Outlook and on the Server using `Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration` both show the intended Messages (internal/external).
- verified that there is no `ForwardingAddress`
- checked for rules using `Get-InboxRule`

... but couldn't find anything.

I'm quite new in this company so i don't know the history of Exchange migrations but got told that it was migrated from 2003 to 2013 with an intermediate step through 2010.

At the Moment the Server is running CU11

Any leads are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is pretty common. 
It is due to the change in the way that Out of the Office was handled between versions of Exchange. It is probably an OOTO from Exchange 2003 days.

The only way I know to resolve it is to flush the rules engine. OOTO is a hidden rule. That will wipe out all rules in the mailbox, so they will need to be backed up or made a note of them.

Then start Outlook thus:

outlook.exe /cleanrules

That will clear the message out.